# gsub with wildcard and several conditions

Tags: r, regex, wildcard, gsub

I am in the process of cleaning up a bibliographic database, first time I work with R. One of the columns, my variable, is a column that contains all the references that the reference in question has cited, and looks for instance like this:

ANDREOSSO-O'CALLAGHAN B, 2008, PALGRAVE STUD EUR UN, P61.   ALECU DE FLERS N, 2005, INT RELATIONS EUROPE, P317.   DUCHENE FRANCOIS, 1973, NATION WRIT LARGE FO.   KOH T, 2007, STRAITS TIMES   0808.   LENZ T, 2009, GEOPOLITICS GEOECONO.   LUCARELLI S, 2010, ROUTL GARN SER EUR W, V7, P1.   MANNERS I, 2002, J COMMON MARK STUD, V40, P235, DOI 10.1111/1468-5965.00353.   NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER MEANS SUC.   ORBIE J, 2010, NORMATIVE POWER EURO.   PORTELA C, 2007, 200710 RSCAS.   ROSECRANCE R., 1998, PARADOXES EUROPEAN F.   SMITH K.E., 2003, EUROPEAN FOREIGN POL.   SONG XN, 2010, REV INT STUD, V36, P755, DOI 10.1017/S0260210510000835.   TANAKA T, 2008, PALGRAVE STUD EUR UN, P170.   WARLEIGH-LACK A., 2010, COMP REGIONAL INTEGR, P43.

The problem that I run into is that the essentially same reference occurs in many different disguises. In the case above, it looks like this

- NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER MEANS SUC.

In other cases, it looks like this:

- NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS,  NEW YORK: PUBLICAFFAIRS

There is at least 30 different unique versions of this reference. I can identify them within my database by name of author - NYE J., the year of publication, 2004, and the mentioning of "the means to suc". So my idea was to use a gsub function that would search within the delimiters in that column (which is a dot and two spaces) for those parameters and replace the whole expression with

- NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS, NEW YORK: PUBLICAFFAIRS

By now, I am able to do simple gsub's, thus I managed to replace all variations of Mr. Nye with the NYE J., but that I did through searching for all variations manually which is now not feasible anymore. I would like to basically do this:

```
help2 <- within(help2, { values <- gsub (x= CR, pattern = "NYE J., 2004,*means to suc*.  ", replacement = "NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS, NEW YORK: PUBLICAFFAIRS")})
```

I am aware that the wildcards work differently in R, but I can't figure out what I would need to change. Anyone an idea? Mant thanks! 
Best regards,
Steffi

Comment: Can these 3 parts come in different order?

Comment: Try https://ideone.com/RD8OPu

Comment: Any feedback?...

Comment: Hi Wiktor, no, they can't, always the same order :)

Comment: Then try my code and if it works I will post with explanations

Comment: Hi Wiktor, I tried to use it, but it didn't seem to work.  I still have entries such as  NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER MEANS SUC, PR10
NYE J, 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITIC, NEW YORK: PUBLIC AFFAIRS
NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS, PP. X. , NEW YORK

Comment: I have used:  pat <- "(?i)(^|\\.  +)NYE J\\.(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*?\\b2004\\b(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*?means suc(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*"
repl <- "\\1NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS, NEW YORK: PUBLICAFFAIRS"
Pat <- within(help, {gsub(pat, repl, help$CR, perl=TRUE)})

Comment: I think the pattern and replacement are correct. So, the problem is with the last line of code you have. Where is the data to modify? A data frame?

Comment: That's correct, it is a dataframe called help, and the text that I had copied in the previous post is one example text from a cell in the column called CR. I have tried to use your sequences in the gsub I know: > test1 <- within(test, { CR <- gsub (x= CR, pattern = "(?i)(^|\\.  +)NYE J\\.(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*?\\b2004\\b(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*?means suc(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*", replacement = "\\1NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS, NEW YORK: PUBLICAFFAIRS")}),got this error Error in UseMethod("within") : 
  no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: Try `help$CR <- gsub(pat, repl, help$CR, perl=TRUE)` - check it please.

Comment: Yes!! It worked, fantastic. Many thanks, I got crazy about this. Thank you also for your patience! What do all the dashes, i's and ?'s do in the above, is there an easy approachable guide to such commands? Best regards, Steffi Winkler

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be the following:

```
pat <- "(?i)(^|\\.  +)NYE J\\.(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*?\\b2004\\b(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*?means suc(?:(?!\\. {2}).)*"
repl <- "\\1NYE J., 2004, SOFT POWER: THE MEANS TO SUCCESS IN WORLD POLITICS, NEW YORK: PUBLICAFFAIRS"
explain$CR <- gsub(pat, repl, explain$CR, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/aMNaxf)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M0xaxw/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?i)` - a case insensitive modifier making the pattern case insensitive
- `(?:^|\.  +)` - start of string (`^`) or a dot followed with 2 or more spaces
- `NYE J\.` - a literal `NYE J.` substring (a dot must be escaped to match a literal dot)
- `(?:(?!\. {2}).)*?` - any char other than line break chars (`.`), zero or more occurrences, as few as possible, that does not start a `.` and 2 or more spaces sequence
- `\b2004\b`  - `2004` as a whole word (as `\b` are word boundaries)
- `(?:(?!\. {2}).)*?` - any char other than line break chars (`.`), zero or more occurrences, as few as possible, that does not start a `.` and 2 or more spaces sequence
- `means suc`  - a literal `means suc` substring
- `(?:(?!\. {2}).)*` - - any char other than line break chars (`.`), zero or more occurrences, as *many* as possible, that does not start a `.` and 2 or more spaces sequence.

The `\\1` in the replacement pattern is a backreference to the value captured in Group 1.